# VBA Timestamp or other tab not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that I am running to paste data into an excelsheet. When I paste the data I want to add the time I did that so I can see when I last updated the data.
I found an easy solution for that:

```
[F2] = Now
```

looks simple and works like a charm. But then there's a problem. This only works if the cell I want the data in is on the same tab as I am running the macro from, but i want that timestamp on another tab. I tried to change the "Overview"tab and back to "Orders" but it doesnt work:

```
Sheets("Overview").Select
[F2] = Now
Sheets("Orders").Select
```

It just gives a 400 error with no explanation. Does anybody know the solution?

Comment: A cell reference with no clearly defined parent worksheet on a worksheet's private code sheet (not a public module code sheet) will always default to that worksheet. Activating another worksheet does nothing to change this.

Comment: @Jeeped - actually this should be the reason why it did not work in first place, the code is most probably in a `Worksheet`, not in a `Module`.

Comment: @Vityata - yes, timestamps are typically produced with a worksheet_change event sub procedure.

Comment: If you really want to use the evaluation shortcut `[...] `, you can explicitly tell the sheet using `[Overview!F2]`

Comment: @Jeeped - I usually produce them in a log sheet, every time I run something...

Comment: @perb -  `[`Shortcuts`']` should not be used in production, and especially not when troubleshooting a problem.  The goal is to remove potential issues, not to add more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore the `Select` completely, it is not needed. Probably the error is somewhere in the logic of the other code. However, this should work:

```
Worksheets("Overview").Range("F2") = Now
```

or with different [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar):

```
Worksheets("Overview").[F2] = Now
```

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)